# Mac Os ANDROID_NDK not set

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

I am trying to run the sample project of the following project: https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia

When I try to start it it gives me the following error message, it says `ANDROID_NDK not set`.

[image]

As you can see from the image android ndk is installed.

[image]

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From the README.md in this GitHub-project:

> If you have Android Studio installed, make sure $ANDROID_NDK is available. ANDROID_NDK=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle for instance.
>
> If the NDK is not installed, you can install it via Android Studio by going to the menu File > Project Structure 
> And then the SDK Location section. It will show you the NDK path, or the option to Download it if you don't have it installed.

So it seems that you need to create a environment variable called ANDROID_NDK which points to your NDK-installation.
Since I use Android NDK for my current project, I know this isn't setup automatically.

Environment variables on MacOS: https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/use-environment-variables-apd382cc5fa-4f58-4449-b20a-41c53c006f8f/mac